# "eth_estimateGas" throws execution reverted error

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, json-rpc, rpc

I was trying to use `eth_estimateGas` but It throws `execution reverted`, The error doesn't indicate anything.
This is my code :

```
    final gas = await _web3Client.estimateGas(
      sender: sender,
      to: toAddress,
      data: data,
      maxFeePerGas: maxFeePerGas,
      maxPriorityFeePerGas: maxPriorityFeePerGas,
      value: value,
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling for a while, I solved the error by removing the value property, I don't know why It threw an error, but I think, Since my case was a erc20 token transfer and has value in data, That might be the reason.
So the final code would look like this :

```
      final transaction = Transaction(
        to: toAddress,
        from: fromAddress,
        maxFeePerGas: maxFeePerGas,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: Config.maxPriorityFeePerGas,
        data: data,
      );
```